# How to validate Json file extension with regular expression

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have a file upload component in EXTJS, I'm using to upload files from computer. However I want to limit it to only JSOn files, so anything other than JSON file extension, should throw some error. now with this function, I'm able to get the filename I clicked to import:

```
    new Ext.Container({
                       height: 100,
                       width: 500,
                       items: [
                          this.fileUpload=  new Comp.form.FileUpload({

                            listeners: {
                                fileUpload: function(filename){
                                  //where filename= "abc.pdf"
                                 //pseudo code below for validation
                                  if (filename===.json) {
                                    console.log("uploaded");
                                    } else {
                                   console.log(“eror”)
                                 }
                                }
                            }
                          })
                       ],
                       scope: this
                     })
```

how to validate the .json file extension, is it possible via Regex??Thanks!

Comment: Why not *not* do that and just verify that the file contents parse as JSON? JSON is designed to be safe to parse (like, there's no way to embed executable code in JSON). Not all platforms treat file extensions as having serious meaning.

Comment: @user1234 do you mean like `/blabla/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the follow function with a regular expression to check the filename extension:

```
function isJSONFile (sFilename) {
    var regexJsonFile = new RegExp(".json$", "i");
    return regexJsonFile.test(sFilename);
}
```

- The function returns **true** if the filename string ends with a json extension, otherwise returns **false**.

Or directly in your code:

```
if (filename.match(".json$", "i")) {
    //It's a json extension
} else {
    //It isn't a json extension
}
```

- The **$** character is used to check only the end of the string and the **i** parameter to use case insensitive.